# MYSQL InnoDB unique key not working properly?

Tags: mysql, innodb, unique-key

I have a really strange problem, and I have no idea what can cause it. Any suggestion will be gratefully appreciated.
Here is the table structures and the queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `big_test` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `account_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dev_id` char(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gid` char(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `age` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `image` longblob NOT NULL,
  `updatedon` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `eik` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `me` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `gid` (`gid`,`application_id`,`account_id`),
  KEY `dev_id` (`dev_id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35796304 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


mysql> SELECT gid, application_id, account_id FROM big_test WHERE account_id=14811 AND gid='TEST773475616236';
+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+
| gid              | application_id | account_id |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+
| TEST773475616236 |           1655 |      14811 |
| TEST773475616236 |           1655 |      14811 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT gid, application_id, account_id FROM big_test WHERE account_id=14811 AND gid='TEST773475616236' AND application_id=1655;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+
| gid              | application_id | account_id |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+
| TEST773475616236 |           1655 |      14811 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT gid, application_id, account_id FROM big_test WHERE account_id=14811 AND gid='TEST773475616236' AND application_id<>1655;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

All the queries which are used for insert/update operations is "REPLACE".
For example:

```
mysql> REPLACE INTO big_test SET gid='TEST773475616236', application_id=1655, account_id=14811, name='Charlie';
```

How is that possible, that UNIQUE KEY is not working?

Comment: I suspect a TRIM might shed some light.You have empty spaces somewhere in those 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problems seems to be in the integer field... I'm not sure TRIM will help? Also I forgot - Server version: 5.5.31-log Distributed by The IUS Community Project

Comment: Try: WHERE TRIM(account_id)=14811 AND TRIM(gid)='TEST773475616236' AND TRIM(application_id)=1655 If its an empty space issue it will return 2 rows.

Comment: SEEMS LIKE: mysql> SELECT gid, application_id, account_id FROM big_test WHERE TRIM(account_id)=14811 AND gid='TEST773475616236'; WORKS!! But this remove the account_id as possible keys to be used, which cause significant delays on the query. How is that possible, that there are spaces in integer field?

Comment: It`s weird,I thought you cant have empty spaces in int column,maybe somebody else will explain it.

Comment: Also I'm casting everywhere account_id to Integer: account_id='".(int)$post['account_id']."'

Comment: Testing a theory: How many rows do you get with this? `SELECT * FROM (SELECT gid, application_id, account_id FROM big_test WHERE account_id=14811 AND gid='TEST773475616236') hack WHERE account_id=14811 AND gid='TEST773475616236' AND application_id=1655;` ...and this: `SELECT gid, application_id, account_id FROM big_test IGNORE INDEX (gid) WHERE account_id=14811 AND gid='TEST773475616236' AND application_id=1655;` ... and please post the response from `SELECT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: Also, please do not change the queries you executed for purposes of either sanitizing or simplifying the output, when posting them here.  You can mask data with xxxx but don't delete things, especially from the query! The optimizer can choose a very different plan depending on which specific columns you select, and we could easily go down the wrong path by assuming the queries you're showing are the actual queries you ran, which they clearly (in retrospect) are not, above, as evidenced by the `+---+` spacing for the output column formatting done by the MySQL command line client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, the problem is not in the database it self, but in the programing code.
There was a SQL statements executed in transaction, where there was a set for stop checking unique keys. Really stupid but answer the question, and solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the envirionment you are running from, but "NAME" is a reserved word in MySQL. I've run into issues on other platforms you need to either back tick it, or change it to big_test.name in the replace statement.

-james